# get the actuel domain name (server name) in Shiny app

Tags: javascript, html, shiny, shiny-server

I have 3 servers, **dev**, **test** and **prod**. My Shiny code shoud be deployed from **dev** to **prod**.

Now the problem:
In the `ui.R` I refere via `href = 'https://dev.com/start/'` to another site named *start*. Is it possible to get the domain name, **dev**, **test** and **prod** automatically? Something like, `href = 'https://**what is the actuall domain**.com/start/'

**addendum**: as DanielR answerd, one can use `session$clientData$url_hostname`, however my problem is taht I need the hostname in `dashboardHeader`. The place in `ui.R` where I need the dynamical `href` is:

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "KRB",
                  
                  titleWidth = 150,
                  
                  tags$li(a(href ='https://dev.com/start/
```

Comment: Any reason you can not just use a relative URL in this place?

Comment: so far I know, I can refer relativly to an index.html, or not? In this case the page start, is created by a shiny app.

Comment: This has nothing to do with an index.html. As long as you _are_ somewhere on `https://dev.com/…`, the relative URL `/start/` would resolve to `https://dev.com/start/`.

Comment: @CBroe you are right!  I thought just I can refere relatively to an index.html. and not to a shiny app, in this case start is the folde of the app. But I was wrong :(. Could you post your answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the problem: In the ui.R I refere via href = 'https://dev.com/start/' to another site named start. Is it possible to get the domain name, dev, test and prod automatically?

For what you want to achieve here, you don’t need to get the actual host name, if you can just use a relative URL instead of a full absolute one to begin with.

Instead of

```
tags$li(a(href ='https://dev.com/start/' …
```

use

```
tags$li(a(href ='/start/' …
```

Relative URLs with a leading slash refer to the domain root, so this should resolve to `https://[hostname]/start/` automatically, without you having to determine what `[hostname]` actually is in this case. The browser basically does that part for you when it resolves relative URLs, based on the address of the currently displayed main document.

Comment: I accepted the answer, however I used 'tags$li(a(href = '../start/'' based on our discussion before. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hostname using the `session$clientData$url_hostname` in your server function. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html

Here's a little app:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('urlui')
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$urlui <- renderUI({
        htmltools::a('my link',
                     href=paste0('http://', session$clientData$url_hostname))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. My Problem is in ui within dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( ... tags$li(a(href =...)) . The question is, how can I pass the hostname into tags$li ?

Comment: Hi. Instead of using the `a` tag directly in the ui, you use `uiOutput` in the ui and output the tag in `RenderUI` from the server.